# What is the meaning of this character hovering in the last jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, luke-skywalker, rey

In the last jedi Rey confronts Luke about what he had done with Kylo Ren. This leads to the two characters fighting with Rey soon pulling out a lightsaber. Luke appears surprised by this and falls backwards. However he doesn't actually touch the ground and is instead left hovering barely above ground. This can be seen in a screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBLsK.jpg

After Rey lowers her lightsaber Luke is seen to stop hovering and falls to the ground, as seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Mhs.jpg

Since the camera cuts into him both hovering and then falling the rest of the way to the ground there appears to be some importance to this but I can't think what it is. Was the hovering supposed to be some sort of defensive measure? This would be supported by the fact that it stops as soon as Rey doesn't appear threatening (since she lowers her lightsaber). But I can't see how that would be helpful in the situation. Perhaps there is some other explanation?

Why was Luke hovering above the ground during his fight with Rey? What was he trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Not crash into the ground? Out of universe, I think this was a subtle way to show us how powerful he had become as he could use the Force even subconsciously.

Comment: Luke is an old man who really doesn't want to slam into the ground. He uses his force powers as he falls back to cushion his fall. I really don't think that it's any more complicated than that

Answer (score 1):

It shows that Luke has reconnected with the Force, after having cut himself off from it. Having reconnected, his default response to falling is to catch himself with the Force.

Comment: Whilst this answer is correct, per my understanding, it would be better to add quotes of him having cut himself off etc.

Comment: FWIW though he has already been shown to have reconnected to the Force at this point so it's a mix of showing he's reconnected but also how powerful he is.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't catch that.